# Material UI - How can I center an IconButton inside the TableFooter?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to center an `IconButton` inside my `TableFooter` using Material UI. For some reason, my current code centers the button a slight bit off to the left and was wondering if someone is familiar with this?

[image: Img]

Here is how I'm attempting to do this:

```
          <TableFooter>
             <Tooltip title="Add">
               <IconButton aria-label="Add" onClick={this.handleAdd} style={{ display: 'block', margin: 'auto' }}>
                  <AddIcon />
               </IconButton>
             </Tooltip>
          </TableFooter>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried with iconStyle prop to the IconButton? If not try apply styles using iconStyle

Comment: @Think-Twice It doesn't seem like `iconStyle` is a recognized prop. `React does not recognize the `iconStyle` prop on a DOM element.`

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @Think-Twice 3.0.3. At least that's what my `package.json` says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the problem actually isn't with my styling. Seems like my styling is correct but the problem is with the width of my table cell. Because I have 2 columns in my data table, my table cell that contained the `Button` component was only spanning the size of one column. Thus, to fix this, I change my `TableCell` to `<TableCell style={{width: "100%"}}>`. This fixed my problem.

Thanks for everyone's input!

Comment: Well react tells:
```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <td> cannot appear as a child of <tfoot>.
```